# Spring don't make autowire

Tags: spring-boot, dao, autowired

i'm finding issues with autowiring in my java application with spring-boot (1.5.17.RELEASE).
In some class the autowire works and in others not. Each class that requires Autowired/Bean is signed as Component and into the application configuration, i made a basepackagescan:

```
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"io.swagger", "io.swagger.api", "com.example.mypackage"},
        excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = Swagger2SpringBoot.class)})
```

The class in wich the autowired doesn't work is that:

```
@Component
public class InputToDomain implements CustomConverter {

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionDAO connectionDAO;

    public Domain convert(Object dest, Object source, Class<?> aClass, Class<?> aClass1) {
        String cod_ = ((Request)source).getCod_();
        return new Domain(connectionDAO.getAnag(cod_));
    }
}
```

The ConnectionDao class is correctly autowired in another class marked equals as this. this is the ConnectionDao implementation:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ConnectionDAO {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConnectionDAO.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private String table = "EXAMPLE_TABLE";

    public List<Anagrafica> getAnag(String cod_){
        SQLQuery sqlQuery = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select * from " + table +" where COD_ = :cod_");
        sqlQuery.setParameter("cod_", cod_);
        sqlQuery.addEntity(Anag.class);

        return sqlQuery.list();
    }

}
```

and is really similar to the class where autowired works. The class's package is included into the ComponentScan.

What should be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Show `ConnectionDAO` class and the package of class

Comment: I added the class, but in another class, the ConnectionDao is well implemented. so the problem is elsewhere...